# converting audio file to wav within react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-state, sox

I currently have the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles/Dropzone.css";

export default function FileDropzone() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const handleDrop = acceptedFiles =>
    setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => file));
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      console.log(files[i]); #outputs audio file as JS file object
    }
}
```

My system essentially allows users to upload audio files with these types: .mp3, .gsm, .wav, .m4a, .mp4. I need to be able to convert whatever file type is uploaded to wav. How can I do this? I research sox and some other alternatives but am not sure. Preferably, I should be able to do this after the console.log. If needed, I can also use node/express backend to do this but id rather avoid making the messy api call with JS objects.

Thanks

Comment: Only `WebM` format is supported in browsers. You can try `vmsg` to convert to `mp3` format using `WebAsseembly`

Comment: please revise *ffmpeg*